# Shared session/login between silex and symfony app

Tags: php, session, silex, symfony

Due to a migration from silex to full stack symfony3, we have both systems running in parallel on the **same host and domain** with a switch in the frontend controller (index.php) based on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']` to decide which framework to bootstrap.

Now the intention is that both systems share the same session AND login/security token. Session data is stored in the Database and the session cookie could have the same name.

As both systems are based on the symfony security component, we thought this would be possible, but it seems that in the session/security token there is some information on the environment/path stored which seems to invalidate the login from one system to the other.

We manged to access the session from one system to the other "manually" by reading the cookie and accessing the database, but it is not working "out of the box". It looks like once the symfony side tries to access the session, we get logged out on the silex side.

Is it possible to configure or extend the security component in a way to make it possible that both systems can share the token "out of the box"?

Does it actually require to use the same "User" class? Because that is not what we are doing (but it seems the namespaced User class is inside the session)

Comment: domains for silex and symfony apps are different?

Comment: Same domain. Framework switch happens based on the ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI'];```

Comment: User classes (that implements AdvancedUserInterface) are the same (full name and attributes)? Try to compare raw session for silex and symfony apps

Comment: Do both apps have the same `session.metadata.storage_key` ? I would check logs to find out what really happens. There are too many moving parts to make an educated guess.

Comment: Also make sure that the firewall name is the same on both apps

Comment: Might there be a `sf_` prefix to the session variables/tokens? Did you dump the full PHP sessions for both installations?